# Isomorphic quotient of a Module over Noetherian commutative algebra

Tags: modules, ac.commutative-algebra, ring-spectra, prime-ideals

I have a nice solution to the following problem and I thought of writing a paper about it but beforehand, I wanted to ask the problem here to see if this is an easy problem and if you people can solve it easily. If its easy then I will not write a paper about my solution. I know of many people who did not manage to solve the problem so lets see if you can.

Let A be a commutative noetherian algebra. Let M be a finitely generated A-module.
For every finitely generated A-module N we define SuppN = V(Ann(N)) \subset Spec(A).

Spec(A) denotes the prime ideals of A.

Ann(N) denotes all the members a of A such that aN=0.

Prove that for any prime ideal p in SuppM, M has a quotient isomorphic to A/p.
Meaning there is an A-module N, which is a submodule of M such that M/N is isomorphic to A/p.

Good Luck :)

Answer (score 5):

This doesn't sound right. Suppose $A$ is an integral domain, and $M$ a nonzero ideal of $A$. Take $\mathfrak{p}=(0)$. You are claiming that there is a surjective homomorphism $M\rightarrow A$. This implies that $A$ is a direct summand of $M$, which happens if and only if $M$ is principal. So any non-principal ideal gives a counter-example.

Comment: In your post you say that $M$ has a *quotient* isomorphic to $A/\mathfrak{p}$. $Am$ is not a quotient... Maybe you should think more about your question.

Comment: No, your quotient $M/N$ is *not* isomorphic to $A$. Again, think more about asking correctly your question. I down vote.

Comment: OK, enough for me. Please learn some algebra before asking questions here.

Comment: Please learn some manners.

Comment: Well here is a counter example to your argument that M is principal. Take M=A^2. And a surjective morphism defined by (1,0)->1. (0,1)->0. Then M is not principal although there is a surjective morphism.

Comment: @Student That's not a counterexample to what abx claimed, because your $M$ is not an ideal of $A$.

Comment: abx's answer is correct. For an explicit example, let $A=\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ be the ring of polynomials in two variables and let $M$ be the ideal consisting of polynomials with zero constant term. Then $M$ does not have a quotient module isomorphic to $A$.